# facebook application bookmark url

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook applications and I would like to modify its bookmark to reroute users to a non facebook url ( my app is wider than the 600px ifram facebook uses)
how can I go about doing that in the App Preference in facebook. there an option for a bookmark url but it only accepts relative link to the canvas page as far as i can tell.
I know this is possible since posterous' app does it.
thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better way but the way I managed it is to create a blank page with the following code javascript:

```
window.parent.location='http://www.homepage.com';
```

and make sure that in the facebook app setting to assign the canvas url to this file

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a canvas location for your app rather than a page tab there is a new option in developer app advanced settings for 'fluid' width, which will give you more than 600px on the majority of visitors browsers.

As far as I am aware, an automatic redirect is against the terms and conditions of Facebook, so don't consider that option.

More about fluid width apps here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
top.location.href="http://mysite.url"